# How to rollback programmaly after functions @Transactionnal worked correctly?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I tried to make a rollback after some functions with @Transational worked

The rollback works when they are errors due to sql and it's commit.

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping()
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Controller {
    private final MyServiceImpl myService;
    @PostMapping("/truc")
public void truc() {
        Entity ent = new Entity();
        myService.createEntity(ent);
        Entity2 ent2 = new Entity2();
        myService.createEntity2(ent2);
        boolean b = {some conditions};
        if(b){
            //to do flush 
        }
        else{
            //to do rollback to get initial state before createEntity()
        }
    }
}
```

MyServiceImpl

```
@Transactional
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SiteServiceImpl {
    //Repositories associed with entities extends JpaRepository
    private RepoEntity repoEntity;
    private RepoEntity2 repoEntity2;

    @Transactional
protected void createEntity(Entity ent){
        this.repoEntity.save(ent);
    }
    @Transactional
protected void createEntity2(Entity2 ent){
        this.repoEntity2.save(ent);
    }
}
```

I would be able to rollback and cancel the two saved entities programmatically. I'm not an expert with Spring and I have no idea how to do. May be with the configuration?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you want to do multiple things and rollback if anything goes wrong, then you should put all your business logic under one method with the @Transactional.

Answer (score 2):

Use `@Transactional` at the `Controller` level . To trigger rollback , throw  `RuntimeException` from the controller.

Something like below:

```
public class Controller {

    private final MyServiceImpl myService;

    @Transactional
    @PostMapping("/truc")
    public void truc() {
        Entity ent = new Entity();
        myService.createEntity(ent);
        Entity2 ent2 = new Entity2();
        myService.createEntity2(ent2);
        boolean b = {some conditions};
        if(b){
            //to do flush 
        }
        else{
            //This will trigger rollback 
            throw new RuntimeException("I want to rollback to cancel what I did in this method");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that this works only for specific values of transaction propagation policy for internal transactions: the `REQUIRED`, `SUPPORTS` or `MANDATORY`. Won't work if propagation is `NOT_SUPPORTED` or `REQUIRES_NEW`.

Comment: Yes Thanks.  Ehcnalb , please pay attention to what @M. Prokhorov said too.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work, it's not commit but not rollback neither, plus it return an error 500 (cause of manual RuntimeException). (I forgot to precise I use org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional)

Comment: I tried with javax.transaction.Transactional, it's the same thing : no commit but no rollback

Comment: you mean in the  exception case , it does not rollback and return 500? What is the stack-trace ?

Comment: I have another problem; if there is a problem with createEntity2, it commit whatever the Entity1 create just before

Comment: how about the success case ? it cannot commit too? Remove all `@Transactional` from `MyServiceImpl` before verifying

Comment: @Ehcnald,  By default, spring rolls back on any `RuntimeException` thrown, but you can change this by setting a `rollbackOn` property in annotations. Also, check that your `Repo` implementation doesn't commit stuff on its own. If it doesn, then you'd get exactly this problem. Repos shouldn't explicitly commit anything on their own, that should be external for them.

Answer (score 1):

You can add new method to your `MyServiceImpl` that call both `createEntity()` methods inside. After that all business logic inside this method will be processed transactionally and automatically rolled back on RuntimeException thrown (use rollBackFor for checked exceptions), because your service class marked as trasactional.
Also all public methods from `MyServiceImpl` becomes transactional if yout add `@Transactional` annotation on your class. There is no need for separate annotation on your methods (except cases, where you want to change some transaction parameters like isolation, propagation, etc.)